# Listbox POSTing but not populating model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have a model that looks like this:

```
    public List<SelectListItem> Interests { get; } = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "Buyers Agent", Text = "Buyers Agent" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "Showing Agent", Text = "Showing Agent" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "Realtor Associate", Text = "Realtor Associate"  },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "Transaction Coordinator", Text = "Transaction Coordinator"  },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "Guest Blog Writer", Text = "Guest Blog Writer"  }
    };
```

The view looks like this:

```
            <div>
                <label for="Interests" class="control-label col-sm-2" style="padding-left: 0px;">Your Interests: </label>
                <select asp-for="Interests" asp-items="Model.Interests"></select> 
            </div>
```

And renders to this:

```
<div>
   <label for="Interests" class="control-label col-sm-2" style="padding-left: 0px;">Your Interests: </label>
   <select id="Interests" multiple="multiple" name="Interests">
        <option value="Buyers Agent">Buyers Agent</option>
        <option value="Showing Agent">Showing Agent</option>
        <option value="Realtor Associate">Realtor Associate</option>
        <option value="Transaction Coordinator">Transaction Coordinator</option>
        <option value="Guest Blog Writer">Guest Blog Writer</option>
    </select> 
</div>
```

If items are selected, they are POSTed back, but controller call shows 0 items in the 'Interests' property of the model.  The controller looks like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Interest()
    {
        var model = new InterestFormViewModel();

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Interest(InterestFormViewModel model)
    {
        // A breakpoint and watch show model.Interests to have a count of 0.

        return View("HRThanks");
    }
```

I must be overlooking something obvious, can someone tell me what it might be?  Thanks!

Comment: You cannot bind a `<select>` to a collection of complex objects. Your model needs a property to bind to - either `string SelectedItem` if you want a dropdownlist, or `string[] SelectedItems` if your want a listbox

Comment: Thanks, I added a string array to the model, changed the asp-for to the name of that array, and it binds wonderfully.  If you make this an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<select>` element posts back a single value (or an array of simple values in the case of a `<select multiple>`. You cannot bind your select to `Interests` because its is a collection of complex objects (`SelectListItem`).

Your model needs a property to bind the selected value(s) to. If you want a dropdownlist, then (say)

```
public string SelectedItem { get; set; }
```

and in the view

```
<label for="SelectedItem" ...</label>
<select asp-for="SelectedItem" asp-items="Model.Interests"></select>
```

or if you want a listbox, then

```
public IEnumerable<string> SelectedItems { get; set; }
```

and in the view

```
<select asp-for="SelectedItems" asp-items="Model.Interests"></select>
```

Note that of you set the value of `SelectedItem` (or `SelectedItems`) in the GET method before you pass the model to the view, and its value(s) match one of the options, then that option(s) will be selected initially.